# Empty string as base case in BNF recursion?

Tags: bnf

I'm writing a small grammar as an exercise for class and my professor didn't really get too specific with what qualifies a legal BNF expression in terms.

The BNF grammar is supposed to recognize strings in this form: AB, AABB, AAABBB, A...B... (general form: AnBn)

So, what I got up to was writing:

```
<S> --> A<S>B | ""
```

My simple yes/no question is whether or not this is legal in BNF, and if not why?

<...> represents a non-terminal, I have no idea if that's convention or what not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is acceptable BNF.  You can see [an example of this on the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) in the example about US postal addresses.

Typically, though, I've seen the empty string represented as ε.